# Should I put glass directly on an aluminum frame for a table?

Tags: glass, table, aluminum

I want to build a table (for my office) from aluminum extrusions (sometimes called 80/20) and I like to put tempered glass on top.

**Can/should I put the glass directly on the metal? Or would it be better to put i.e. a 2mm rubber strip in between?**

I am not 100% sure about the table design until now. Until now I think I will us 3060 aluminum extrusions in a rectangle of 120cm x 75cm size. And then I will put 6mm tempered glass on top. I will use the table for my office/computer work.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Think the rubber would cut down on any vibrations transmitted from table to glass(glass to table) and smooth out any differences in flatness of the two.  It won't hurt to have it.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you'll be able to build a frame which is as flat as the sheet of glass. So the result will be that without some flexible spacers to take up the gaps there's likely to be some annoying wobble and unnecessary stress on the glass.

Comment: This isn't a home improvement question, but you should use clear silicone buttons. They'd be much less visually intrusive than strips. Also, aluminum can scratch glass. You need something just to eliminate rattles.

Comment: I'll add that in a pinch, a dab of hot glue on each corner will work. If you get the glass down while the glue is still soft, it will "self level" to an extent, and each glue piece will solidify at just the correct height so that each of them are guaranteed to be (and stay) in contact with the glass, despite any potential height discrepancies between each corner of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do use rubber as a barrier between the glass the the frame.

Note: The comments are all good answers. I answered this question just so that it would be marked as having an answer.